# How to reload a Python script

Tags: python, refresh, reload

i am very new to python and I wanted to ask how to reload a Python script, like I want to make a button inside an script that says Reload and when you press on it it refreshes the script, so that I do not have to close it and open it again. Is there any way to do this, I need a step by step guide.

Thanks

Comment: Share your current code, or we won't be able to help you

Comment: The reload function (built-in function in Python 2, contained in module imp in Python 3)  might be what you are looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python refresh/reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517038/python-refresh-reload)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reloading it could you use a while loop and have a user input rather than a button as python doesn't have any simple GUI like html  tags so:

```
refresh = "refresh"
while(refresh == "refresh"):
    print("code")
    refresh = input("Type refresh to refresh: ")
```

Apologies for all the edits.

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear what you mean with "reload", but the normal behavior of Python is that you need to restart the software for it to take a new look on a Python module and reread it. also you cannot add buttons inside a python script ... for that you may need to use HTML or other ..