# python: reload module inside function

Tags: python, reload

i have a configuration file in python that can be changed while the main script is running, so i need to reload it.

i tried the answer in this post:
[python refresh/reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517038/python-refresh-reload)

```
import config
from config import *
...
reload(config)
from config import *
```

it worked until i entered the reload part to a function, so if i do this:

```
import config
from config import *

def main():
    reload(config)
    from config import *
```

i get the warning: 'import *' only allowed in module level, the script is running but the reload isn't working,

i also tried "import config" instead of "from config import *" but i got an exception "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'config' referenced before assignment"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33068321/6253693 seems like an option for reloading in a function

Comment: Using a module like that as a config file is _not_ a good strategy. Reloading modules is just a convenience while you're developing. You shouldn't do it in production code, because there's a good chance that not everything will get changed by the reloading process. Use a proper config file.

Comment: Also, "star" imports are best avoided in normal scripts: they dump a bunch of names into your namespace making it impossible to distinguish the local names from the imported ones, and possibly leading to name collisions, especially if you do star imports from more than one module.

Comment: it's not a big script but i'll keep that in mind, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to store your configuration in a file rather than a module. Please take a look at the `ConfigParser` module from Python. From what I've heard, it can handle ini files too.