# How can we refresh our Windows with python just like we do at the desktop (right click and click to refresh)

Tags: python-3.x

Please somebody help me!
I'm new here.
I am tired of searching it online.
Is it possible to do refresh the Windows with python?
If it is possible, then can we do it with 'os' module in python?

```
import os
```

Comment: This question/answer might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517038/python-refresh-reload

Comment: @Rick Colgan, I think he did not mean to reload package, but wants to call some windows api which in turn will do the same thing as pressing right click on desktop and clicking on refresh.

Comment: @mergenchik Yes, Exactly! I want the same like you said.Thank you man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pyautogui as dp
import time

dp.hotkey('win', 'd')

dp.position(x = 1920,y =540) ### You can change x and y based on the resolution of your pc
dp.click(x = 1920,y =540,button = 'right')

dp.click(x = 1900,y =620)## These coordiantes are not universal, changes as per the pc resolution
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jai Shankar! It is working fine.